# How to click at button with almost same class using Protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I have several buttons with two classes:

```
<button _ngcontent-c39="" class="btn btn-block"></button>
<button _ngcontent-c39="" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"></button>
```

I need to click at all buttons with class **"btn btn-block"** and don't want to click at the button with the class  **"btn btn-block btn-primary"**. 
I already tried:

```
element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-block')).click();
```

but Protractor click at these two button.
I already tried using className locator, but protractor doesn't find the element.

```
element.all(by.className('.btn.btn-block)).click();
```

Comment: Are their parent elements different? You can reference them as a child of a parent

Comment: No, their parents are the same

Comment: I think $('button[class="btn btn-block"]') should work. But I do not have time to test it.

Comment: It did! Thanks.

Comment: great! I am glad for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
element.all('button[class="btn btn-block"]').each(function(element){
element.click();
});
```

and worked.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I could come up with is doing regex checks.

```
element(by.all('.btn-block')).each(function(element)
{
  let tmp = element.getAttribute('class');
  if(/^btn btn-block$/.test(tmp)) element.click();
}
```

Basically this will loop through every element that has the `.btn-block` class, and then check to make sure that it has EXACTLY `btn btn-block` and if it does, it clicks that element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `each()` method and click each button that does not contain `btn-primary` class.

```
var allButtons = element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-block'));
allButtons.each((button) => {
    button.getAttribute('class').then((buttonClass) => {
        if (!buttonClass.includes('btn-primary')) {
            button.click();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: For some reason, protractor returns  element no visible for this solution

Comment: How does the app work? Does the element disappear after clicking on it?

Comment: No, it's just change its class.
I already found the solution:
element.all('button[class="btn btn-block"]').each(function(element){
element.click();
});